# Validate composite entity's properties uniqueness

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

Does any one knows how can I validate the composite uniqueness of two entity's properties without creating a custom validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass several fields to the annotation:

```php
@UniqueEntity(fields={"firstField", "secondField"})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i mistakenly tried UniqueEntity with the wrong syntax an thought it won't be able to check multiple fields. Thanks so much!